# What is the best way to store mysql tree relation changes?

Tags: mysql, tree, revision-history

I found the solution of doing it, but I don't like it. Because each time we change one relation we must duplicate all tree records instead of one record. Who have any ideas how to do it in other way, or optimize my - you are welcome! Thanks!

The simpliest self to self tree table:

```
`categoies`
    id|parent_id|label|
    --+---------+------
    1   NULL      A
    2   1         B
    3   2         C
    4   3         D
    5   4         E
```

"A > B > C > D > E" nested set

I want to save all relation changes. I think that I need to do it in this way:
add table revisions

```
`revisions`
id |       created       |
---+----------------------
1     2015-02-02 09:00:00
2     2015-03-02 09:01:00
3     2015-04-02 09:00:00
4     2015-04-07 09:02:00
```

change table `categories`

```
`categoies`
    id|label|
    --+-------
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D
    5   E
```

add table `category_revisions`

```
    `category_revisions`
        id|rev_id|category_id|parent_category_id|
        --+------+-----------+-------------------
        1   1         1           null
        2   1         2           1
        3   1         3           2
        4   1         4           3
        5   1         5           4                # A > B > C > D > E

        6   2         1           null
        7   2         2           1
        8   2         3           1
        9   2         4           3
        10  2         5           4                # A > B 
                                                   #   > C > D > E
```

Comment: What is the purpose of storing the revisions?

Comment: I want to create web page routing tables group, which must to monitor all changes of routes and do automated redirects to actual links if requested older.

Comment: Why then not simply have a table which stores "old link" and "new link"?

Comment: let's imagine next:
we have categories /cat1/cat2/cat3/ <1000 pages inside.html>.
later seo master do /technics/cat1/cat3/<1000 pages inside.html>
and again /home-technic/cat3/<1000 pages inside.html>

So how large will be your table "old link storage" after 3 step of changes?

Comment: 3k rows... My advice: if it's size you're concerned about, don't be. 3k rows is nothing, and it's important to keep it simple!

Comment: no. it means + 1k of rows during each change of tree structure. I'm searching for universal solution of HTTP STATUS CODE response system